# I want to invite the member to team on tfs but getting error 'No identities found'

Tags: tfs

I am getting error "No identities found" when inserting member to my team. I've verified the email address is correct. Why am I seeing this text? How can i fix this?
[why cannot found?](https://pasteboard.co/GWWHskQ.jpg)

Comment: Have create a tfs server?

Comment: Of course. I have a tfs server. You can see in the picture. Have 3 members registered

Comment: After creating team project go through this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/add-users-team-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your screenshot, you are working on VSTS, you could double confirm this-- sever url should like `https://xxx.visualstudio.com`.

And you want to login VSTS with an non Microsoft email, you should pay attention to below:

> ***Sign up for Visual Studio Team Services with a work or school account***
>
> Control access to Visual Studio Team Services the same way you do with
>   Microsoft services like Office 365 and Azure. When you sign up with a
>   work or school account, your Visual Studio Team Services account is
>   connected to your organization's directory (tenant) in [Azure Active
>   Directory (Azure AD).](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-whatis/) You can then use the same username and password
>   as other Microsoft services, like @fabrikam.com. Azure AD helps you
>   enforce policies around accessing your team's critical resources and
>   key assets.

More details, please refer link from MSDN: [Sign up for Visual Studio Team Services: Git & Agile for DevOps, continuous integration, & continuous delivery](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/sign-up-for-visual-studio-team-services#orgaccount)

Finally, just follow the details steps in this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/add-users-team-project) to add users to a team project.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use an Active Directory account for on-premise TFS -- you can't provide a hotmail account.